# Menus in game: Is Screenmanager the way to do it?

Tags: python, kivy

I'd like to create a menu in my game coded thanks to Kivy, where the player can choose different options and launch the game.

I've learned about the ScreenManager module but I don't know whether it's taylored for this:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, NoTransition

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class GameScreen(Screen):
    gameloop.main()

class MyGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
       sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
       sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
       sm.add_widget(GameScreen(name='game'))
          return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyGameApp().run()
```

If I do this, isn't the app launching simultaneously the Menu AND the Game screen at the same time (one in the background and the other shown to the user)? (which is not what is intended of course).

What is the proper way to do a menu in games with kivy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a game's logic in screen widgets.

If your game has some kind of count down, or moving enemies, you can bind its start to `on_pre_enter` or `on_enter` [events](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen).